# Tensorflow ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental_functions_run_eagerly' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function' jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have 'Tensorflow ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental_functions_run_eagerly' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function' everytime I try to import tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow_examples.models.pix2pix import pix2pix
import keras

import os
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
import cuda

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

import PIL
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
```

above is the code I used.

below are my packages.

```
Package                      Version
---------------------------- ---------
absl-py                      1.4.0
aiohttp                      3.8.1
aiosignal                    1.2.0
astunparse                   1.6.3
async-timeout                4.0.1
attrs                        21.4.0
blinker                      1.4
brotlipy                     0.7.0
cachetools                   5.3.0
certifi                      2022.12.7
cffi                         1.15.1
charset-normalizer           3.0.1
click                        8.0.4
conda                        23.1.0
conda-content-trust          0.1.3
conda-package-handling       1.9.0
cryptography                 38.0.1
flatbuffers                  23.1.21
frozenlist                   1.2.0
gast                         0.4.0
google-auth                  2.16.0
google-auth-oauthlib         0.4.6
google-pasta                 0.2.0
grpcio                       1.51.1
h5py                         3.8.0
idna                         3.4
importlib-metadata           4.11.3
keras                        2.11.0
Keras-Applications           1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing          1.1.2
libclang                     15.0.6.1
Markdown                     3.4.1
MarkupSafe                   2.1.2
mkl-fft                      1.3.1
mkl-random                   1.2.2
mkl-service                  2.4.0
multidict                    6.0.2
numpy                        1.22.4
oauthlib                     3.2.2
opt-einsum                   3.3.0
packaging                    23.0
pip                          22.3.1
pluggy                       1.0.0
protobuf                     3.19.6
pyasn1                       0.4.8
pyasn1-modules               0.2.8
pycosat                      0.6.4
pycparser                    2.21
PyJWT                        2.4.0
pyOpenSSL                    22.0.0
PySocks                      1.7.1
python-version               0.0.2
PyYAML                       6.0
requests                     2.28.2
requests-oauthlib            1.3.1
rsa                          4.9
ruamel.yaml                  0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib             0.2.6
scipy                        1.7.3
setuptools                   66.1.1
six                          1.16.0
tensorboard                  2.11.2
tensorboard-data-server      0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit       1.8.1
tensorflow                   2.11.0
tensorflow-estimator         2.11.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.30.0
termcolor                    2.2.0
toolz                        0.12.0
tqdm                         4.64.1
typing_extensions            4.4.0
urllib3                      1.26.14
Werkzeug                     2.2.2
wheel                        0.38.4
wrapt                        1.14.1
yarl                         1.6.3
zipp                         3.8.0
```

The code and the import process worked perfectly fine until this morning. I am using vscode, python 3.9.13, jupyter notebook(server:local). I was trying to use virtual linux environment using ubuntu, in order to enable gpu computing. I didn't use anaconda/miniconda before then.

The error is generated on the very first line(import tensorflow as tf). I tried disabling the first 3 lines, but importing keras also creates the same error.

I also tried to import tensorflow-gpu, but pip suggested to install tensorflow instead. I followed tensorflow install document(https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?hl=ko#windows-wsl2_1).

I updated wsl from 1 to 2, but this error keeps happening.

Comment: Try uninstalling the modules first by `pip uninstall keras-nightly` and 
`pip uninstall -y tensorflow` and then install the following: 
h5py==2.10.0
tensorflow==1.15
tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0
keras==2.1.6

Comment: The solution was [here](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/2637)

Comment: Hi @Euna J, Could you please try upgrading Python to `3.10` version or try by installing `tensorflow 2.10` in your system? Also try installing pix2pix api from `pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git` before importing. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you.

Comment: @TFer2 the issue still persists. I installed tensorflow 2.10 instead upgrading python to 3.10. pix2pix is already installed by the code you gave me. thanks.

Comment: @GautamChettiar the issue still persists. I removed keras and tensorflow entirely and tried again, but tensorflow-gpu is not existing anymore and there's also errors while installing h5py. the solution you gave me is 2y old and is using different python version, so I don't think that would help. thanks anyway.

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-wsl2) for GPU support configuration and install all required software.